# Laptop White Screen after changing LED display cable

Tags: laptop, display, white-screen

a few Weeks ago I noticed my Laptop screen flicker while opening/adjusting the lid. The flickering became worse, and the screen went white more and more often. I took a look inside, and noticed that the flickering became worse (or went away) when I pulled at the Display cable. I assumed the cable was broken and ordered a new one.

I have replaced the cable, but the screen remains white. Any Idea why that is?
Most forum posts I have read on the subject say, that in this situation, the Display might be broken. Is there any way I can confirm this to be the case?

Something I have noticed:
While I was searching for the problem (before the cable replacement) I noticed that I had to pull out the display cable before the laptop would accept an HDMI connected monitor as the primary display. Now, after the replacement, the laptop prefers the HDMI monitor to the integrated one.

My laptop is an Asus X550LA.

Comment: Sounds like the solder joints on the connector have broken.